# Grab ordered records grouped by ID where the first record of that group == 10

Tags: sql, database, web-sql

Using [W3 Schools SQL Server Query Tool](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_groupby) I remove the contents and enter the following:

```
SELECT * FROM OrderDetails
ORDER BY ProductID, Quantity;
```

And click `Run SQL`.  It nicely orders by the `ProductID` and then for tie breakers on `ProductID` It orders by `Quantity`.

Here is what I want to do. With the table ordered as above: I want to `group` together the `ProductID`'s on this table, and then return only those `ProductID` groups where the **first record of each group's** `Quantity` amount is `== 10`.

I attempted something like this but it doesn't work:

```
SELECT * FROM OrderDetails
ORDER BY ProductID, Quantity
Group By ProductID
Having first(Quantity == 10);
```

Comment: That tool doesn't use MySQL. It uses WebSQL because it's running in the browser.

Comment: Are you trying to find a list of all the products that have a 10 as the lowest quantity that has been ordered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I read this correctly, you want all the products that have 10 as the smallest  quantity that has been ordered in productId order.

```
SELECT productId,  min(quantity) as first FROM OrderDetails
group by productId
having first = 10
ORDER BY ProductID
```

EDIT to answer comment below.
The same logic will work with a string column.  In this example, I'm showing all suppliers where the first product (with products listed alphabetically) starts with a C (try it in the W3 query tool).  If I had data that any repeating string data, I could have done an `=`.

```
SELECT supplierId, min(productName) as first from products
group by supplierId
having first like 'C%'
order by supplierId
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this but use `equal to`? Your solution works for this exercise, but I'm trying to apply this to a real world problem where the condition is on a string, and I'm trying to see if a column on that first `product` per group of products is exactly equal to a string.

Comment: Are you usining one column to find the 1st row and checking another column is equal to something?  Or do you just want to replace quantity with a string column?

Comment: replace quantity with a string column.

Comment: as in pretend `quantity` was a string column and not a number. And the `having` clause is to see if it is equal to a string.